# Would object fall out of scope?

Tags: c#, .net, destructor

Quick question.

Consider this code

```
public class Tile
{
    public Collision Collision;
    public Tile()
    {
        Collision = new Collision(this);
    }
    public ~Tile()
    {
        CollisionHandler.Remove(Collision);
    }
}

public class Collision
{
    public Collision()
    {
        CollisionHandler.Add(this);
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public Main()
    {
        Test1();
        Test2();
    }

    public void Test1()
    {
        Tile[,] tiles = new Tile[20,20];
        tiles[0,0] = new Tile();

        tiles[0,0] = new Tile();
        //Would calling the above call the old Tile's destructor?
    }

    public void Test2()
    {
        Tile[,] tiles = new Tile[20,20];
        tiles[0,0] = new Tile();

        Tile t = new Tile();
        tiles[0,0] = t
        //Would calling the above call the old Tile's destructor?
    }
}
```

Now, when I run `Test1` would the old `Tile`'s finalizer
 be called? What about `Test2`?

Comment: FIrstly: They're called `Finalizers` in C#. They aren't the same. Secondly, what's stopping you from testing this yourself?

Comment: I'm on my phone on an airplane, wanted to know because I am rough drafting some features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing about destructors (proper name is "finalizers") in C# is that you never know when they will be called. It can be called as soon as the object falls out of scope. It can be called when your program ends. In some situations, they may even not be called at all. It is all up to the garbage collector.

So do not use destructors for your system logic. There are not all that many situations when you should use destructors at all.

Comment: Well butts, it would have been nice if the second it falls out of scope it gets collected. I'll have to figure something else out if I the Tile beneath the Collision gets taken out.

Comment: Implement IDisposable and wrap the Tile class in `using` statement

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no.

The objects aren't finalized until the Garbage Collector decides it wants to. At no point in this are you doing anything remotely like C++'s `delete`. You're just allocating a new portion of memory and changing a pointer (roughly).

As stated in the comments: Finalizers (C#) and Destructors (C++) aren't the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I'll have to look elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete. If it were complete, the reference objects would be chained like `CollisionHandler->Collision->Tile`, so your neglected `Tile` would never get collected by garbage collector anyway.

The .NET GC is non-deterministic, so if you are looking for something like automatically managed deterministic destructor so you are out of luck. .NET framework provides `IDispose` interface for the situation where deterministic clean up is preferred e.g. File I/O operation, but the consumers have to aware of this and calling `Dispose` explicitly or by using the language's feature like `using` keyword in C#.